# Airflow tasks getting killed with "Scheduler heartbeat got an exception" error

Tags: mysql, airflow

I have a dag which runs 4 tasks which are all bash operators. Recently i moved to airflow version 1.10.2. I am seeing the below error frequently:

```
ERROR - Scheduler heartbeat got an exception: (MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError) (1213, 'Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction') (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

I am using mysql as backend for metadata. I check the value of variable innodb_lock_wait_timeout in my mysql:

```
mysql> show variables like 'innodb_lock_wait_timeout';
+--------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name            | Value |
+--------------------------+-------+
| innodb_lock_wait_timeout | 50    |
```

which is not very high to get this issue.
Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Your exception doesn't reference a lock timeout but instead says a deadlock occurred; the `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` variable is not consulted for deadlocks if `innodb_deadlock_detect` is enabled, which it is by default.

Try setting `innodb_deadlock_detect=OFF` in the database configuration.